# How to restrict using classes from dependency in source code, but allow it at compile time in maven

Tags: java, maven

In my maven project I have dependency `A` with transitive dependency `B`.
Dependency `A` provides classes that are required for the project. Both of this libraries are provided by the platform (scope `provided` is used).

I would like to restrict usage of dependency `B` (classes that it provides) in the source code, however I can't exclude it because compilation is failing (classes from `A` that I have to use, extend classes from `B`)

`B` contains way more classes than is required for compilation and runtime. Avoiding of using those comes from idea to depend on third-party code as least as possible, for later refactoring.

**Is there any maven plugin that can provide such functionality?**

`A` and `B` are third-party dependencies and there is no control over them. Java 8 is used.

Comment: There are two options to go with. The first one using [checkstyle](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/) or https://www.archunit.org/ could be a solution restrict the usage of classes...

Answer (score 0):

There is none, because that would not work. If you use class `A'` from dependency `A` and `A`is extending `B'` from dependency `B` then your own code needs to be able to access `B'`. There is no way around that.

I can only imagine a situation where `A` uses interfaces from `C` that are implemented in `B`. Then you could limit compile time access to `A` and `C` and provide the interface implementations in `B` only at runtime (this is pretty much how plugin systems work (providing interfaces that are implemented in modules not available at compile time).